# What is the equivalent of this mysql_result() in terms of mysqli_result()

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$query = "SELECT `uid` FROM `userdata` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'";
$query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Note :- $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pword);

```
$query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
$user_id = mysql_result($query_run,0,'uid');//How do convert this line to mysqli_result() function???
```

Comment: There isn't really one; you have to pull the whole row and then select the desired result from the resulting array.

Comment: Can u provide me the code for it?

Comment: you want to get the `uid` row? you need to fetch it first

Comment: Yes, because I wanted to echo it out like this for testing purpose :-                  echo $user_id = mysql_result($query_run,0,'uid'); //But how do I replace this line of code with mysqli_result() ?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_enc = sha1($password);
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
        $query = "SELECT `uid` FROM `userdata` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password_enc'";
        if($query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
          $query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
            if($query_num_rows == 0) {
                echo 'Invalid username and password combination';
            } else if($query_num_rows == 1) {

Comment: echo $user_id = mysql_result($query_run,0,'uid'); // I wanted to just replace this line by mysqli_result(), what could be the code here?
            }
        } 
    }

Comment: @sachintendulkar edit your question, and no you cannot get the value that way, you need to fetch it first

Comment: The answer is :- replace                                            $user_id = mysql_result($query_run,0,'uid'); with                     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
                echo $row['uid'];

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :- replace the line

```
$user_id = mysql_result($query_run,0,'uid');
```

with

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
            echo $row['uid'];
```